# Create GeoJSON layer based on remote server request (ArcGIS JS API)

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm starting with ArcGIS JS API. I'm doing the following POST request to my remote server:

```
esriRequest("php/load_gisdata.php", {
    method: "post",
    query: {
        table: "participants_loc",
        fields: "*",
        geometry_column_name: "geom"
    },
    responseType: "json"
}).then(function(response) {
    // The requested data
    console.log(response);
    var geojson = response.data;

    const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(geojson)], {type: "application/json"});
    const url  = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const lyr = new GeoJSONLayer({ url });
    map.add(lyr);

});
```

the `geoJson` variable is correctly returning the GeoJSON (point type, srid: 4326) I want to plot.

It's giving the following message:

```
"[esri.layers.graphics.sources.GeoJSONSource] Some fields types couldn't be inferred from the features and were dropped"
```

Someone could help me out how to plot this geojson features from the remote server request?!

Comment: You can hack a local renderer to plot multiple geometry classes, but loading into server-side layer probably requires exactly one. What happens if you split the steam into three distinct pieces?

Comment: Per the GeoJSONLayer doc, and your error, can you confirm the field attributes are standard across all features? `Each GeoJSONLayer will only accept one schema of the properties. The fields property can be used to specify the desired fields for the layer. If fields is not defined, the schema used by the first feature will be used to deduce the fields schema for the layer.` Otherwise can you define the fields in your JS code, or even cut your geojson down to just a single feature and try that.

Comment: Also, (once you've made sure the field properties are correct), if your PHP application supports GET, you could probably simplify the core to avoid the esriRequest+stringify+createObjectURL and just use the GeoJSONLayer directly.